# Liquibase generate changelog from JPA entities

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I have a Spring boot, spring data jpa project with a parent and three children modules.
One of my modules is responsible for my JPA entities.
I need generate one xml changelog with liquibase from this entities.

In my liquibase.properties i have the code:

```
changeLogFile=src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
username=root
password=root
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
outputChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/db/outputChangeLog/liquibase-outputChangeLog.xml
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:br.com.company.vacation.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
diffChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase-diff-changeLog.xml
```

So, if i try execute the command: **liquibase:diff** i receive the error:

In my pom.xml i configured the liquibase just like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
    </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate4</artifactId>
                <version>3.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

If i execute the **liquibase:generateChangeLog** the liquibase generate the log from my existing database...
But if i tried execute **liquibase:diff** i receive the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.1:diff (default-cli) on project vacation-club-web: Execution default-cli of goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.1:diff failed: A required class was missing while executing org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.1:diff: org/springframework/orm/jpa/persistenceunit/DefaultPersistenceUnitManager
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-maven-plugin/3.4.1/liquibase-maven-plugin-3.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/ext/liquibase-hibernate4/3.5/liquibase-hibernate4-3.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.1.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.4.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.1.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-envers/4.3.1.Final/hibernate-envers-4.3.1.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.0.4/plexus-utils-1.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/lucas.araujo/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.4.1/liquibase-core-3.4.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager
```

Someone already had this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i solved this problem.

The solution is one dependency it's missing in my pom.xml file.

Pom.xml

```
<!-- Liquibase -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
    </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate4</artifactId>
                <version>3.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</plugin>
```